# Multiple M2M in django

Tags: django, model, m2m

I have two models in Django for a 2d map based game:

```
class Block(models.Model):
   type = models.IntegerField()

class ShopBuilding(models.Model):
   house_blocks = models.ManyToManyField(Block)
   street_blocks = models.ManyToManyField(Block)
   river_blocks = models.ManyToManyField(Block)
   decoration_blocks = models.ManyToManyField(Block)
   npc_blocks = models.ManyToManyField(Block)
```

Now I just want associate these two models using ONE table:

```
class ShopBlockAssoc(models.Model):
    block = models.ForeignKey(Block)
    shop = models.foreignKey(Shop)
```

After I set the `through` field in `ShopBuilding` model, Django yiled multiple fails when syncdb, like

```
    Error: One or more models did not validate:
tnew.shopbuilding: Accessor for m2m field 'house_blocks' clashes with related m2m field 'Block.shopbuilding_set'. Add a related_name argument to the definition for 'house_blocks'.
tnew.shopbuilding: Accessor for m2m field 'house_blocks' clashes with related m2m field 'Block.shopbuilding_set'. Add a related_name argument to the definition for 'house_blocks'.
tnew.shopbuilding: Accessor for m2m field 'house_blocks' clashes with related m2m field 'Block.shopbuilding_set'. Add a related_name argument to the definition for 'house_blocks'.
tnew.shopbuilding: Accessor for m2m field 'house_blocks' clashes with related m2m field 'Block.shopbuilding_set'. Add a related_name argument to the definition for 'house_blocks'.
tnew.shopbuilding: Accessor for m2m field 'street_blocks' clashes with related m2m field 'Block.shopbuilding_set'. Add a related_name argument to the definition for 'street_blocks'.
tnew.shopbuilding: Accessor for m2m field 'street_blocks' clashes with related m2m field 'Block.shopbuilding_set'. Add a related_name argument to the definition for 'street_blocks'.
tnew.shopbuilding: Accessor for m2m field 'street_blocks' clashes with related m2m field 'Block.shopbuilding_set'. Add a related_name argument to the definition for 'street_blocks'.
tnew.shopbuilding: Accessor for m2m field 'street_blocks' clashes with related m2m field 'Block.shopbuilding_set'. Add a related_name argument to the definition for 'street_blocks'.
tnew.shopbuilding: Accessor for m2m field 'river_blocks' clashes with related m2m field 'Block.shopbuilding_set'. Add a related_name argument to the definition for 'river_blocks'.
tnew.shopbuilding: Accessor for m2m field 'river_blocks' clashes with related m2m field 'Block.shopbuilding_set'. Add a related_name argument to the definition for 'river_blocks'.
tnew.shopbuilding: Accessor for m2m field 'river_blocks' clashes with related m2m field 'Block.shopbuilding_set'. Add a related_name argument to the definition for 'river_blocks'.
tnew.shopbuilding: Accessor for m2m field 'river_blocks' clashes with related m2m field 'Block.shopbuilding_set'. Add a related_name argument to the definition for 'river_blocks'.
tnew.shopbuilding: Accessor for m2m field 'decoration_blocks' clashes with related m2m field 'Block.shopbuilding_set'. Add a related_name argument to the definition for 'decoration_blocks'.
tnew.shopbuilding: Accessor for m2m field 'decoration_blocks' clashes with related m2m field 'Block.shopbuilding_set'. Add a related_name argument to the definition for 'decoration_blocks'.
tnew.shopbuilding: Accessor for m2m field 'decoration_blocks' clashes with related m2m field 'Block.shopbuilding_set'. Add a related_name argument to the definition for 'decoration_blocks'.
tnew.shopbuilding: Accessor for m2m field 'decoration_blocks' clashes with related m2m field 'Block.shopbuilding_set'. Add a related_name argument to the definition for 'decoration_blocks'.
tnew.shopbuilding: Accessor for m2m field 'npc_blocks' clashes with related m2m field 'Block.shopbuilding_set'. Add a related_name argument to the definition for 'npc_blocks'.
tnew.shopbuilding: Accessor for m2m field 'npc_blocks' clashes with related m2m field 'Block.shopbuilding_set'. Add a related_name argument to the definition for 'npc_blocks'.
tnew.shopbuilding: Accessor for m2m field 'npc_blocks' clashes with related m2m field 'Block.shopbuilding_set'. Add a related_name argument to the definition for 'npc_blocks'.
tnew.shopbuilding: Accessor for m2m field 'npc_blocks' clashes with related m2m field 'Block.shopbuilding_set'. Add a related_name argument to the definition for 'npc_blocks'.
```

If I set `db_table` field Django says:

```
The model has two manually-defined m2m relations through the model, which is not permitted. Please consider using an extra field on your intermediary model instead.
```

How could I fix this? I really want to make sure those shop-block relations are using the sharing the same intermediate associate model with the same db_table

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that on model `Block` it tries to create backwards links. Django names those links based on Model, in your case for all ManyToMany it tries to create `shopbuilding_set` and names collide. To avoid this add `related_name`, for example:

```
class ShopBuilding(models.Model):
   house_blocks = models.ManyToManyField(Block, related_name="shopbuilding_house_set")
   street_blocks = models.ManyToManyField(Block, related_name="shopbuilding_street_set")
   river_blocks = models.ManyToManyField(Block, related_name="shopbuilding_river_set")
   decoration_blocks = models.ManyToManyField(Block, related_name="shopbuilding_decoration_set")
   npc_blocks = models.ManyToManyField(Block, related_name="shopbuilding_npc_set")
```

Then you'll be able to access `ShopBuilding` from `Block` instance like this:

`block.shopbuilding_npc_set.all()`

Comment: yes thanks, but how do I make sure these fields using the same intermediate model?

Comment: if you want one intermediate model you don't create 5 ManyToMany relations, you create just one. like blocks = models.ManyToManyField(Block) and that's it. Problem is that when you have one intermediate model you can't have "types"

Comment: so basically Django ORM doesn't support multiple same m2m with one assoc model?

Comment: You can create Model, add "type" field and specify that model in Through. But it's harder to create such objects because you'll always have to specify "type" field and etc. Django doesn't merge many manytomany relationships into one. You can always create some "accessors" and managers that helps you deal with your custom relationship (DRY).

Comment: Anyhow in question you specified your `ShopBlockAssoc` model that is standart manytomany relationship. Basically it's the same as writing `blocks = models.ManyToManyField(Block)`. You can select all blocks from ShopBuilding and you can select all shops from block but you don't have types like house, street, river.